# Python Unicode ajax form posting error

Tags: python, django

i got a n00b problem with python and i've been searching here for a while and i couldnt find a proper solution...

i got a utf8 form that i ajax post to a python page. i read the json simplejson with utf-8 charset.

the text is fine as long as there is no mixed utf8 and latin chars like ?!;, etc...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

```
commentjsonarray = simplejson.loads(commentjson, encoding='utf-8')
```

i tried a bunch of things but i cant get it to work.
help.

### just an update for you with more code for help, thanks

commentjson = request.POST['commentObj']

```
commentjsonarray = simplejson.loads(commentjson, encoding='utf-8')
program = get_object(Program, commentjsonarray['programid'])
userget = get_object(User, commentjsonarray['userid'])
#get user avatar from usermeta
usermeta = get_object(UserMeta, 'user_id = ',userget.key())
commenttext = commentjsonarray['walltext']
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode,force_unicode,smart_str

commenttext = smart_str(commenttext)

newcomment = db_create(Wall, user_avatarurl=str(usermeta.avatarurlsmall),user_fullname=str(''+userget.first_name+' '+userget.last_name),user_idstring=str(userget.key()),text = str(commenttext) , program_id = program.key() , user_id = userget.key())
```

above is the python part.
here is the javascript:

```
var walltext = $('walltext').value

 var commentObj = {"walltext": ""+walltext+"", "programid": programid, "userid": userid};
 var commentJSON = encodeURIComponent(Object.toJSON(commentObj));
if (walltext != '' || walltext == 'type here' || walltext.length > 0) {

    new Ajax.Request('/wall/new', {
        method: 'post',
        encoding: 'UTF-8',
        parameters: 'commentObj=' + commentJSON,
        onSuccess: function(request){
            var msg = request.responseText.evalJSON();
            if (msg) {

                var structure = '<div id="' + msg.msgid + '"><img src="' + msg.avatarurl + '" width="18" height="18"> ' + msg.username + ':' + msg.text + '<div id="frontSepLine"></div></div>';

                //$('programwall').insert({bottom:structure});
                refreshWall(msg.programid);

                $('walltext').value = 'type here';

                var objDiv = document.getElementById("programwall");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;


            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: So can you add a `print(repr(commentjson))` just before the `simplejson.loads` call that fails and show us exactly what's in it at that point?  All the Javascript code you now do show, and the Python code that's intended to run _after_ the failure point, gives no real indication whatsoever of the root cause of the failure, nor of how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you've described works fine for me (with the standard library `json` on Python 2.6), either with or without the explicit encoding (which is not needed for a utf-8 encoded bytestring, as utf-8 is the default here):

```
>> s = u'{"valá":"macché?!"}'.encode('utf8')
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'val\xe1': u'macch\xe9?!'}
>>> json.loads(s, encoding='utf-8')
{u'val\xe1': u'macch\xe9?!'}
```

and also with simplejson 2.1.1 (really redundant on 2.6, but, oh well;-):

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> s = u'{"valá":"macché?!"}'.encode('utf8')
>>> simplejson.loads(s)
{u'val\xe1': u'macch\xe9?!'}
>>> simplejson.loads(s, encoding='utf-8')
{u'val\xe1': u'macch\xe9?!'}
```

Can you describe your problem more accurately?  Your description of what triggers your error, i.e. the reverse of "as long as there is no mixed utf8 and latin chars like ?!;, etc", doesn't cause any problem -- so what about showing us the tiniest example that *does* reproduce your problem?

Comment: hey, did you review it by any chance?

Comment: @Alon, sure -- see my comment to your Q, posted 2 hours after your edit: until you add that print and show us its results, you're stalling any chance of us debugging your problems.  Why have you ignored that for well over a week?!